# jQuery: appending content to a <div> with a certain id

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have some code which generates lots of textboxes using jQuery. At the moment it just adds them to the bottom of the page in my form.

I have created a div called "timearea" that I'd like to put these textboxes in. How do I append to it using jQuery?

```
<div id="timearea"> </div>
```

This is the current code I tried but it broke my js.

```
  $('body').append('timearea');
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery selectors require a '#' prefix for IDs and '.' prefix for class names, otherwise jQuery thinks you are trying to select a DOM element by its name (like 'div' or 'ul').

Try this (`.html()` grabs the contents of your selected element):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').append($('#timearea_DIV').html());
    });
</script>
...

<div id="timearea_DIV">
    <div id="timearea"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does not work it just prints along the bottom of the page timeareatimearetimerea

Comment: sorry, try containing the "timearea" div within a container.   .html() grabs the contents of the selected element..

Comment: sorry x 2.. I forgot to add '$' before the second selector. Updated my example.

Comment: nope still doesnt work my javascript comes before the div in my page is that a problem?

Comment: No problem, your javascript can be placed anywhere within the <head> or within the <body>. Just contain any jQuery code within $(document).ready() so that it runs after the dom has finished loading

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
$('#timearea').append([html for textbox]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct use of append would be to add the actual HTML:

```
$('body').append('<div>timearea</div>');
```

Notice that i've omitted the id, because if you're doing it multiple times you can't have multiple IDs (it would need to be a class).

This is assuming that you wanted to add a div to the bottom of your document, the question isn't clear.

If you wanted to add some HTML to the 'timearea' div, you need:

```
$("#timearea").append("[some HTML here]");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#timearea').appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').append($('#timearea'));
```

Do note though that the original node will be actually moved instead of copied after using append().

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('body').append(($('#timearea')).html());
```

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) you will get basic concept on JQuery ID Selector.